# Calculating R-squared with same data but different regression model

Tags: regression

Using the same data, two different regression models are produced.

e.g 
Regression 1: height= 5+ 3(father's height) + u

In regression two we have height= 0.02+ 5.1(father's height) + u

These models are different because in model 2, height was measured in feet.

Assuming these regressions used the same data, is the R-squared value identical between the two?

I was under the assumption that it would be the same.

Comment: Won't change as long as your transformation is linear.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your question is "If I change the units, will R^2 change?" and the answer is "no". However, the intercept should not change.  This is intuitive but can be demonstrated easily e.g. in R (everything after a # is comment):

```
set.seed(1234)  #Sets a seed
x1 <- rnorm(1000)
x2 <- x1*12  #Changes units
y <- 3*x1 + rnorm(1000,0,5)   #creates y
m1 <- lm(y~x1)  #fits a linear model
m2 <- lm(y~x2)

summary(m1)  #R^2 = 0.3083, y = 0.08 + 3.28x1
summary(m2) #R^2 = 0.3083, y = 0.08 + 0.27x1
```

Comment: The OP says that "height" is measured in feet in the second model. I'd assume that this refers to *both* the IV (father's height) *and* the DV (height). In which case, yes, $R^2$ shouldn't change (the *proportion* of variance explained doesn't change), but the intercept should certainly do.

Comment: @StephanKolassa If both IV and DV are measured in the same unit, the parameter 3 is dimensionless and should not change.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: yes, but we are discussing the *intercept*, not the coefficient for father's height.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Sure, but this observation shows that most definitely DV and IV are *not* measured in the same unit in both models, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: ah, I see your point. You are right. The OP's example seems to be broken. Thank goodness the question still makes sense.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I agree -- the OP should specify more precisely what is measured in which unit, to make this a well-defined question.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify in regression 1 both heights are in metres. In regression 2, the height in metres is converted to feet and that regression is calculated.

Comment: @dramastical Are you sure they are not in millimeters? Because 5mm is about 0.02 feet (up to some rounding).